# Including files, overwriting variables

Tags: lua

I'm trying to overwrite the variables in my first .lua file, by requiring a second on, at the end of my code.

file1.lua

```
val = 1
require "file2"
```

file2.lua

```
val = 2
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, as val is still 1 after this. The solution I came up with, to allow the potential future users of those files to include files, is a new function, which I'm for now inserting when initializing Lua:

```
function include(file)
    dofile("path/since_dofile_doesnt_seem_to_use/package/path" .. file .. ".lua")
end
```

This works exactly as expected, but since I'm still new to Lua, I'd like to know, if there might be a better solution. Maybe there's something already build in?

**Update:**

My problem was that I've accidentally required file2 multiple times, over multiple files, and Lua wouldn't load it again, to change the value. Solved.

Comment: If `val` is global then your first try should work.

Comment: Well, no "local", it should be global. That's what confused me as well. I've just tested this in pure Lua, and there it's working...? I'm running file1 with luaL_dofile, and there it's not working, this is strange.

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to post your C(++) code then

Comment: I've found the problem... I'm running multiple files, and one accidentally required one, that I've run later as well. It appears this caused problems... after the first dofile, the value wouldn't change, unless I've included additional files with dofile. If I use require, the value doesn't change... quite unexpected.

Comment: Yes, lua keeps track of which files have been `require`d so you can't `require` the same file twice.

Comment: you can thwart that behaviour by setting `package.loaded[packagename] = nil`

Comment: @SethCarnegie, please include your comment as an answer so the quesdtion can be marked as "answered".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua keeps track of all the files you have `require`d in your code in a table called `package.loaded`. Every time a file is `require`d, that table is checked, and if the module name exists in the table already, it is not loaded. If it does not exist in the table, the module is loaded and the name is added to the table. This way you can `require` a module many times but it will only be run the first time.

You can get around this by setting `package.loaded[packagename] = nil` after `require`ing the package. That way, when lua checks if the package name exists in the table, it will not find it, so you can require it as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

in file2.lua

```
print(val)
_G.val = 2
print(val)
```

output should be

1

2

Comment: maybe if you could describe a little more exactly what you're trying to accomplish i could point you a bit more in the right direction... _G is the built in lua way to access/set global variables created in the local or imported scopes. anything else you do would be a glorified wrapper around calling _G.var = value

Comment: i can't comment on the above post, but to answer the require question... lua has a built in guard against require recursion. if file A requires file B, and file B requires file A, when file A loads, it'll load file B up until the point that file B requires A. so if you have some functionality that needs to be exposed in file B to file A, that code would have to go before the require("fileA").